# LINQ Query for filter by Selected Items in Checkbox List

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects, checkboxlist

Could not find this through Google or in SO questions...

I have a checkbox listbox on my form. I want to filter my List by the list of selected Ids from that listbox that are checked, in SQL I would have done this like "Where TypeId In (1, 4, 5, 7)"... how do I do that in LINQ?

I feel like I am missing a really obvious answer, but cannot get it.

For argument sake... here is the what I have for sample data:

```
In Colors (List<of currentColors>)
ID, Name, TypeId
1, Red, 1
2, Blue, 1
3, Green, 2
4, Pink, 3
```

Selected Types 2 and 3 in CheckboxList: filteredColors

```
filteredResults = (From C In WorkItemMonitor Where ????).ToList()
```

Expected Items in filteredResults would be:
[3, Green, 2], [4, Pink, 3]

EDIT:
My Current Query.. (sorry was told it would be an list, turns out to be a datatable I am filtering)

```
Dim workItemsListing As DataTable
workItemsListing = (From L In WorkItemMonitor.AsEnumerable() _
Where clbStatus.CheckedItems.Contains(L.Item("CurrentStatusId"))).CopyToDataTable()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<CurrentColor> colors = chkListCurrentColors.CheckedItems.Cast<CurrentColor> ();
filteredResults = (From C In WorkItemMonitor colors.Contains(C.TypeId)).ToList()
```

That's about the best I can do with your description.  If you need more help, you'll need to show how what you add to the CheckedListBox and the Type of your colors.

Comment: How does that know what I have selected?

Comment: More information, sorry just got the change as I was working on this... I think it is close, but I am getting "The source contains no DataRows", though both object have items. Is this because I need to cast the CheckedItems collection to a datatable?

Comment: What is the type of value in clbStatus.CheckedItems?  `clbStatus.CheckedItems(0).GetType()`  You need to cast it to that type.